# Unmet dependencies; cant upgrade the system

Tags: debian, apt, dependencies

I tried to `apt --fix-broken install` and there is an output:

```
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 binutils : Depends: binutils-common (= 2.31.1-11) but 2.34-5 is installed
            Depends: libbinutils (= 2.31.1-11) but 2.34-5 is installed
            Depends: binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu (= 2.31.1-11) but 2.34-5 is installed
 cpp-8 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8.2.0-21) but 8.4.0-1 is installed
 g++-8 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8.2.0-21) but 8.4.0-1 is installed
 gcc-8 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8.2.0-21) but 8.4.0-1 is installed
         Depends: libgcc-8-dev (= 8.2.0-21) but 8.4.0-1 is installed
 libgfortran5 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8.2.0-21) but 8.4.0-1 is installed
 libstdc++-8-dev : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8.2.0-21) but 8.4.0-1 is installed
                   Depends: libgcc-8-dev (= 8.2.0-21) but 8.4.0-1 is installed
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8.2.0-21) but 8.4.0-1 is installed
```

But I cant downgrade any of them due to this error again.
There are no held packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you posted is everything that was shown from the start of the error message to the last line before the terminal prompt?  Apt is usually Debian related and I do not see any `dpkg` related error message on the last line.

If this is Debian based (the `apt` is not a ported package), then try the bellow:

Instead of using `apt` to fix the packages, try using `dpkg` to fix the problem.  Run the command `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq --dry-run binutils binutils-common libbinutils binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu gcc-8-base gcc-8-base cpp-8 g++-8 gcc-8 gcc-8-base libgcc-8-dev libgfortran5 libstdc++-8-dev libstdc++6`

Because we are doing dryrun here it will not do anything, all it will do is just pretend as if it were to do it, and what the theoretical outcome would be if the above command was done without `--dry-run`.  If it works, then try running it without  the `--dry-run`.

After that is done, try upgrading the system again.

If this is not a Debian type of Linux system, please tell what type of UNIX or Linux system this is.

Comment: Actually, I found out that this problem follows from the previous one https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/579342/stuck-on-unpacking-python3-blinker . So the whole upgrade is broken. Can you help with it?

Comment: `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq --dry-run binutils binutils-common libbinutils binutils-aarch64-linux-gnu gcc-8-base gcc-8-base cpp-8 g++-8 gcc-8 gcc-8-base libgcc-8-dev libgfortran5 libstdc++-8-dev libstdc++6 python3-blinker ...` at the ... add the other dependencies and packages that display on the error message.  If this works, run the command without `dry-run`.

Comment: @ Amol Soneji I got the output like https://imgur.com/b2i8MlG

Comment: That is a normal situation, the reason being is that you do not know in advance what depends on what.  Since this issue happened during an update that was stopped abruptly, this type of warning from running the above was bound to happen.  To fix this add the depends on packages to the command above.  Add the other dependencies and packages that display on the warning message message.  If this works, run the command without `dry-run`.